# is it possible to call a TypeScript method like array index?

Tags: javascript, oop, typescript

This is the way we can get an array by its index:

```
var theArray=[];
theArray['something']=="Hello!";
console.log(theArray['something']); //Print "Hello!"
```

Now imagine the same thing, I have a function and I'm going to call it; Like this:

```
export class myClass {
    public callByIndex(theIndex:string) {
        //this is how it works:
        this.doSomething()

        //And these are the ways I need to call them:
        this.theIndex //of course error!
        //or
        this[theIndex]; //Another Error! How to do it?
    }

    private doSomething (){
        console.log("Yesss, I called!");
    }
}

let callTest = new myClass();
callTest.callByIndex("doSomething"); //Here I give the method name!
```

How is it possible?

Comment: Index of what? You need object/array to get value based on given index. `this.someArray[theIndex]`

Comment: @Oen44 I know what you mean, that's why I'm asking, I know about JavaScript object/array that's why I said **"like array  index"**, I need to call methods like how we can access arrays by their index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, arrays in Javascript are just plain objects (`{ }`) with interger properties. So to invoke a function using the square brackets, just pass the name of the function you want to execute to it

```
class Test {
  dummyFunction(arg) {
    console.log('dummyFunction called with argument: ' + arg);
  }
}

let test = new Test();
test['dummyFunction']('this is a string');
```

Comment: Wisely answer! Great. How is the same thing possible from inside the `dummyFunction` method? Imagine `Test` class has another method, and `dummyFunction`'s `arg` argument job is to call those methods according to the given argument. *(the given argument is other methods name)*

Comment: Then inside `dummyFunction`  just do `this[arg]()` to execute that particular function assuming that the function with name stored in `arg` takes no argument

Comment: @M98 the square brackets in Javascript is actually a property access syntax, functions are just properties of a given object (or type), the nice thing about the square brackets syntax is that it allows you to pass arbitrary expression to it, if it evaluates to a value which does not resolve to an existing property, `undefined` is returned

Comment: Thank you so much for the great answer. It helped me to learn something new again.

Answer (score 0):

If the object is based on an **Interface** some of the members might not be callable (they are not functions). In this case you must specify exactly which member names are allowed as an index.

Also this only works if the parameter type of the member functions is the same but you can overcome this limitation with type `any` and check for correct parameters inside your function.

```js
    interface OnlyMethodsIf {
        sayHi: (val: string)  => void;
        sayBye(val: string): string;
    }

    const onlyMethods : OnlyMethodsIf = {
      sayHi: (val: string) : void =>  { /* do some stuff */ },
      sayBye(val: string) : string { return 'someString'}
    }

    //if all members are callable we can just use "keyof OnlyMethodsIf" as  member type
    const callToOnlyMethods = (member: keyof OnlyMethodsIf, val: string) => {
      onlyMethods[member](val);
    }


    interface MixedMembersIf {
        sayHi: (val: string)  => void;
        sayBye(val: string): void;
        word: string; //not a method/function
    }

    const mixedMembers : MixedMembersIf = {
      sayHi: (val: string) : void =>  { /* do some stuff */ },
      sayBye(val: string) : string { return 'someString'},
      word: "Ola",
    }

      //this will not work, "word" is not a callable member of MixedMembersIf
      const callToMixedIncorrectly = (member: keyof MixedMembersIf, val: string) => {
      mixedMembers[member](val);
    }

    // defining which members are callable - 'member: "sayHi" | "sayBye"'
    const callToMixedCorrectly = (member: "sayHi" | "sayBye", val: string) => {
      mixedMembers[member](val);
    }


    //real life use case
    const callMathFunction = (
      type: 'round' | 'ceil' | 'floor' | 'trunc',
      num: number,
    ) => {
      return Math[type](num);
    };
```

Here is an example of how to overcome **same type for function members** limitation:

```js
 
    interface OnlyMethodsNoLimits {
        sayHi: (param: any)  => number;
        sayBye(param: any): string;
        sayNothing: () => void;
    }

    const onlyMethodsNoLimits : OnlyMethodsNoLimits = {
      sayHi: (param: any) : number =>  { 
         /* check param type here */ 
        console.log("called 'sayHi', param:", param);
        return param
      },

      sayBye(param: any) : string { 
         /* check param type here */ 
        console.log("called 'sayBye', param:", param);
        return param
        
      },

      sayNothing: () : void =>  { 
        console.log("called 'sayNothing'");
      },

    }

    const callToOnlyMethodsNoLimits = (member: keyof OnlyMethodsNoLimits, param?: any) => {
      return onlyMethodsNoLimits[member](param);
    }

    console.log("sayHi with number param returns:",callToOnlyMethodsNoLimits("sayHi", 53));
    console.log("sayHi with string param returns:",callToOnlyMethodsNoLimits("sayHi", "a string"));
    console.log("sayHi withouth param returns:",callToOnlyMethodsNoLimits("sayHi"));

    console.log("sayBye with number param returns:",callToOnlyMethodsNoLimits("sayBye", 53));
    console.log("sayBye with string param returns:",callToOnlyMethodsNoLimits("sayBye", "a string"));
    console.log("sayBye withouth param returns:",callToOnlyMethodsNoLimits("sayBye"));

    console.log("sayNothing with number param returns:",callToOnlyMethodsNoLimits("sayNothing", "a string"));
    console.log("sayNothing with string param returns:",callToOnlyMethodsNoLimits("sayNothing", 53));
    console.log("sayNothing withouth param returns:",callToOnlyMethodsNoLimits("sayNothing"));
```